# Named Range Worksheet parent from Workbook object

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to obtain a reference to the Worksheet object in a child Workbook.

Is there a better way to obtain the Worksheet reference from a Child Workbook?

What i have now:

`activeworkbook.Names("rngMarketAreaMgr1").RefersToRange.Worksheet.Name`

Seems a little long and over-dot'ing to get the name.  As the Range refers ultimately to a Defined Table on a worksheet, the Table (in theory) could move to a different worksheet so i need to refer logically to the NamedRange at the Workbook level to then extract the Worksheet object to then work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
Debug.Print Range("rngMarketAreaMgr1").Parent.Name
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout thats assuming its in the currentwb and doesnt access the Workbook object.  And i explicitely stated at the Workbook level not the abstract reference to the currentwb ;)

Comment: @GoldBishop: If I understand you correctly then adding the workbook name before the above range won't help your problem?

Comment: @SiddharthRout considering that Workbook doesnt expose a Range Property/Method, only the Worksheet, yeah i just want to make sure the form i have is the most effecient, as i will be access Ranges acrossed Workbooks, in a process, so i need to make sure that i have the best possible (not lazy) way of accessing the Range and by derivative the Worksheets Name.

Comment: `so i need to make sure that i have the best possible (not lazy) way of accessing the Range` @GoldBishop: lazy way?

Comment: lazy way: using implicit references that assume Workbook/Worksheet focus.  I like to do explicit object references so i know exactly what workbook/worksheet i am using when performing operations.

Comment: @GoldBishop: Ah Yes my apologies. You are absolutely right on that account. I always fully qualify my objects but didn't do so in this case.